# tftp-hpa won't register tftpd-hpa service on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, tftp

I tried installing the tftp-hpa package as per [TFTP - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TFTP), but it will not install (not properly at least).

```
user@host:/etc/default$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

```
user@host:/etc/default$ sudo apt install tftp-hpa -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  tftp-hpa
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 19.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 63.5 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 tftp-hpa amd64 5.2+20150808-1ubuntu4 [19.0 kB]
Fetched 19.0 kB in 0s (49.4 kB/s)   
Selecting previously unselected package tftp-hpa.
(Reading database ... 245715 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../tftp-hpa_5.2+20150808-1ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking tftp-hpa (5.2+20150808-1ubuntu4) ...
Setting up tftp-hpa (5.2+20150808-1ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
```

```
user@host:/etc/default$ apt list --installed | grep tft

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

tftp-hpa/focal,now 5.2+20150808-1ubuntu4 amd64 [installed]
```

```
user@host:/etc/default$ sudo service tftpd-hpa status
Unit tftpd-hpa.service could not be found.
```

```
user@host:/etc/default$ ls 
acpid            anacron       cacerts        dbus       intel-microcode  libvirtd             nss       saned      virtlogd
acpi-support     apport        console-setup  grub       irqbalance       libvirt-guests       openvpn   ufw
alsa             avahi-daemon  crda           grub.d     kerneloops       locale               qemu-kvm  useradd
amd64-microcode  bsdmainutils  cron           im-config  keyboard         networkd-dispatcher  rsync     virtlockd
```

The `apt` installation process does not:

1. Create and register the tftp-hda service
2. Create the `/etc/default/tftpd-hpa` configuration file

I expected those two to happen, but they did not. Where do I go looking for breadcrumbs/logs for this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed `d` while installing the package, i.e., `tftp-hpa` is TFTP client while `tftpd-hpa` is the server.

If you run `apt show tftp-hpa` and read description, you'd see

```
Description: HPA's tftp client
 Trivial File Transfer Protocol (TFTP) is a file transfer protocol, mainly to
 serve boot images over the network to other machines (PXE).
 .
 tftp-hpa is an enhanced version of the BSD TFTP client and server. It
 possesses a number of bugfixes and enhancements over the original.
 .
 This package contains the client.
```

On the other hand, `apt show tftpd-hpa` would return

```
Description: HPA's tftp server
 Trivial File Transfer Protocol (TFTP) is a file transfer protocol, mainly to
 serve boot images over the network to other machines (PXE).
 .
 tftp-hpa is an enhanced version of the BSD TFTP client and server. It
 possesses a number of bugfixes and enhancements over the original.
 .
 This package contains the server.
```

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated.